# Default to DT_STR (ANSI 1252) while connecting with IBM DB2 Provider for SSIS

Tags: ssis, db2, connection-string

I am attempting to connect to a DB2 database using the IBM native OLE DB Provider.  The default behavior of this connector is to treat varchar, char, and text data as OLEDB type = `DT_WSTR` (unicode)

*edit: Why do I need this?*

This is needed to prevent having to do a manual data conversion (from `DT_WSTR` to `DT_STR`) within SSIS for each string column encountered from the DB2 database.  In my use case there are hundreds if not thousands of instances of this).

*edit: Which Version of DB2?* = **DB2 v11.1.3.3**

I have been searching the IBM help documentation and forums for answers on how I can change the connection so it defaults string/varchar data to `DT_STR` (ansi, 1252).

It appears there are some useful keywords I can potentially use in the connection string, but all of my trails are not successful...

- [REPORTSTRINGASWSTRING](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.oledb.doc/ids_oledb_038.htm)
- [UNICODE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.oledb.doc/ids_oledb_037.htm)

Connection Strings that I tried...

```
Data Source=<<source_removed>>;User ID=<<user_removed>>;Provider=IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1;Persist Security Info=True;Location=;UNICODE=FALSE;CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.CP1252;DB_LOCALE=en_US.819;Extended Properties=REPORTSTRINGASWSTRING=FALSE;

Data Source=<<source_removed>>;User ID=<<user_removed>>;Provider=IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1;Persist Security Info=True;Location=;CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.CP1252;DB_LOCALE=en_US.CP1252;Extended Properties=REPORTSTRINGASWSTRING=FALSE;

Data Source=<<source_removed>>;User ID=<<user_removed>>;Provider=IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1;Persist Security Info=True;Location=;UNICODE=FALSE;Extended Properties=REPORTSTRINGASWSTRING=FALSE;
```

The source columns are defined in DB2 as ...
and the DB2 locale is `En_US`

```
PARN_LOCN_RM_CD           VARCHAR(15),
PARN_LOCN_RM_DESC         VARCHAR(255),
```

This is how it is currently behaves, but I would like it to default to `DT_STR`
[image: data flow wstr]

Comment: Can you edit the question to explain why you need this?  Also, can you mention the codepage+territory of the Db2-server-data-source.

Comment: Which version of DB2 are you connecting to?

Comment: Your description is about DB2, but your link is to IBM Informix.